# Connect custom class with CoreData

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, oop, core-data

Is it possible to add custom class(not inherited from NSManagedObject) as Entity in CodeData?

Or that is the best way to do if I have Custom class(user profile). 
I want to save some users in Core data. Problem is that my Custom class will be changed in future. So,  I want that Custom class and CoreData Entity will be inherit from one class. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All entities in Core Data are instances of, or instances of subclasses of, `NSManagedObject`. You have no choice about this.

If you only want to save some user profiles then you should maintain a subclass of `NSObject` which you usually use and which is able to be created from an `NSManagedObject` instance (that you have fetched from the data store for that purpose). You will also need a way to create / update an `NSManagedObject` instance with new details from this user profile class.

If you change the user profile class but not the attributes of the entities in the Core Data model then you don't need to do a migration of the data store.

Comment: That depends entirely on what properties you have which are shared. It's your business logic...